# Java Criteria builder- how to build a complex join query?

Tags: java, backend, criteria-api

I'm new to Criteria API (and JAVA in general, but lets not talk about this). 
I'm trying to build a really complex query using it, which goes like this:

```
 SELECT ac.firstName as firstName, ac.lastName as lastName, du.idNumber as idNumber, du.dateOfBirth as dateOfBirth, du.gender as gender, du.settlement as settlement, du.street as street, du.buildingNumber as buildingNumber, du.id as driverID, pa.phoneNumber as phoneNumber, ea.emailAddress as emailAddress
 FROM newDB.accounts ac
 inner join driver_users du on du.id = ac.id
 inner join phone_authentications pa on pa.identity_id=ac.identity_id
 inner join email_authentications ea on ea.identity_id=ac.identity_id
 where du.idNumber=:searchParams.idNumber and  emailAddress like searchParams.emailAddress
```

After a lot of digging I managed to understand the syntx of the Criteria API and how to work with it, but im not sure on few things:

1. how do I make it pull out of various tables? I saw the "Root" command where you define the root table to pull from, so I guess my case should be `Root<DriverSearchResultDto> root = criteriaBuilder.from(DriverSearchResultDto.class);`, but is it really the root? Just assumed so because it came after the "from" clause... and what about the inner-joins? how do I add them with the specified join condition?
2. The `DriverSearchResultDto` I based my criteria-builder upon is not an entity and not connected directly to a table, its a custom DTO I created to recieve the results from the query. Is it ok? I went through the rest of the code written before I got here, and all the criteria-builders used are actual entities conneted to DB tables, so I wanna make sure I'm using it right (the fields inside has the exact same names tho- e.g firstName, lastName, etc).
3. how do I make a "like" condition in criteria? couldn't find a lot of info on this as well.
4. a newbie question about queries- I didn't get to work much on sql DBs lately. I'm not really new to the syntax but just not sure about something: as you can see, all the paramters I wanna pull from the DB are written like `ac.lastName as lastName`- no change to the name of parameter itself. Is it just the previous programmer being weird, or is it necessary when pulling from few tables at the same time (or on other condition?) to specify paramters name to not include table? will it not know how to parse the response into the results object?

Tnx alot!

Comment: Do you want a SQL solution or pure "Criteria API" solution?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what do you mean by "sql solution"? there isn't much about SQL in the question except for 4, which should be pretty short and decisive answer I believe. 
What I really need here is the Criteria-API solution to my questions :)

Comment: You tagged it with `sql`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name well there are some SQL elements here... or do you think its mistagged? anyway, I'll glad to have w/e answer you got in mind :)